# Sliding panel oscillates while mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a div container with HTML and jQuery, where when you hover over it another panel slides over the top. But I am experiencing the sliding panel "yoyo" about. I think this is because when the panel slides over the div the hover state is triggered then lost and so the panel pops up and down again continuously.

What I want to happen is while you are hovering over anywhere in the square the panel shows and when you are not in the square it doesn't.

Here is a fiddle so you can see what the problem is, maybe it is easier explained this way.

https://jsfiddle.net/xa5gtd2u/3/

Also here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="services-blocks">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1974" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Design" width="250" height="250" />
    <h3>title here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="services-slide-panel">
  <h3>title here</h3>
    Some text here
    Some text here
    Some text here
    Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .services-slide-panel {

  background: #f3535e;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.services-slide-panel h3 {

  color: #ffffff;

}

.services-blocks h3 {

  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.container {

  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
```

jQuery

```
      $(document).ready(function() {


    $(".services-blocks").hover(function() {

      $(this).next(".services-slide-panel").slideToggle("slow");

    });

  });
```

Comment: You should try animate instead of toggle in this case. The first div would trigger the animation for the second div. The second div would then trigger when the user mouses out.

Comment: I agree with @tintyethan. As well you should look at jQuery [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), specifically `.stop(true)` so that repeatedly hovering doesn't cause the animations to run repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 transition is always a better pick to do these kind of effects. Moreover you have to `hover()` on `.container` otherwise the slided in div will take the hover instead and the will invoke hoverout part of the `hover()` function.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {


    $(".container").hover(function() {

      $(this).find(".services-slide-panel").addClass("slow");

    }, function() {
      $(this).find(".services-slide-panel").removeClass("slow");

    });

  });
```

```css
.services-slide-panel {
  background: #f3535e;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 110%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.services-slide-panel.slow {
  top: 0%;
}

.services-slide-panel h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.services-blocks h3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="services-blocks">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1974" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Design" width="250" height="250" />
    <h3>title here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="services-slide-panel">
    <h3>title here</h3> Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xa5gtd2u/6/)**

Comment: You forgot the `overflow:hidden;` on the `.container`. Also, should really put your sample code here, not leaving it on an external site. +1 for not jQ as the solution you gave, btw.

Comment: Works a treat thanks. I used to avoid CSS transitions due to compatibility. But looking at the support its fairly irrelevant these days. Thanks again.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions